# Java 16 records BigDecimal equals & hashcode

Tags: java, bigdecimal, java-16, java-record

We use Lombok in our everyday project and I love it for the brevity it introduced. We have a tone of BigDecimal properties and with a little bit of effort made them ignore the scale in Lombok's generated equals and hashCode methods. Is there a way to do this in new record classes introduced in Java 16?

Comment: Note that the `equals()` contract of records is quite strong; it must be the case that "cloning" a record by calling its accessors and feeding the results back to the canonical constructor results in an equals instance.

Comment: The philosophy of records would rather be to enforce that instances of `BigDecimal` are always scaled the same way when creating the records rather than overriding the `equals`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're after a general way to alter how `equals` and `hashCode` are implemented for fields that have a specific, existing type. There's no way to do this.

You have two options:

1. Implement `equals` and `hashCode` yourself on every `record` you define, like:

```
record Test(BigDecimal v) {
    public int hashCode() {
        return Util.hashCodeWithoutScale(v);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return Util.equalsForBigDecimalWithoutScale(this, o);
    }
}
```

2. Consistently use a wrapper that you define:

```
record Test(BigDecimalWrapperThatIgnoresScaleInHashCodeAndEquals x) {
}
```

> For us this feature seems unusable.

While `BigDecimal` is close to your requirements, the mismatch in behaviour suggests you may have better luck with use of a wrapper, or an alternate class instead, even if it largely delegates to the existing class.